# Automatically create a new Google Spreadsheet with Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

How to automatically create a new Google Spreadsheet with Script Editor?

I know it seems obvious but I couldn't find an answer to this as everyone has only been interested in creating a sheet, instead of an entirely new spreadsheet automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create anew spreadsheet refer to the create() method there : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname

Code is really simple

```
function createNewSpreadsheet(){
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("My New Spreadsheet");
  Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());
}
```

And if you want to get the first tab

```
  var firstTab = ssNew.getSheets()[0] ;
```

And if you want to get the cell C15

```
  var cell = firstTab.getRange("C15");
```

Stéphane